# Calculating characteristic polynomial of linear transformation, cofactor expansion?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

My question more is if cofactor expansion is really the best way to calculate the characteristic polynomial here:

3. Linear transformation: $$T: P_2(R) -> P_2(R)$$
   defined by $$T(a_o + a_1x + a_2x^2)= (-15a_0 - 4a_1 + 8a_2) + (25a_0 + 7a_1 -13a_2)x + (-15a_0 - 4a_1 + 8a_2)x^2$$

Using the basis $$ β = \{ 1,x,x^2 \}$$

I calculated the matrix representative to be \begin{pmatrix}-15&-4&8\\ 25&7&-13\\ -15&-4&8\end{pmatrix}

To calculate the characteristic polynomial:
$$P_T(λ) = det([T]^β_β - λI)$$

$$P_T(λ) = \begin{pmatrix}-15-λ&-4&8\\ 25&7-λ&-13\\ -15&-4&8-λ\end{pmatrix}$$

From this step I'm not too sure. This is a subset of a larger problem that would be on a test so would have to compute this by hand but not looking to learn a new technique I guess. Just through the usual cofactor expansion, this seems like a difficult one to get $P_T(λ)$ and eigenvalues.

Am I overlooking something/any ideas?